# How do I send a message on only one channel in irssi, if I have joined to multiple channels?

Tags: irssi

I've read over the manual at http://www.irssi.org/documentation/manual and tried googling directly but I cannot figure out how to send to a particular channel if I am connected to multiple channels.

A related question is, when I am in multiple channels, does irssi default to sending messages to one channel or only the most recently joined channel?

Answer (score 1):

I was considering deleting this question since I just figured it out through experimentation, but I will leave it for the future in case anyone else looks for this.

The active channel appears to be the one most recently joined, and you have to reissue the `/channel #new_active_channel` command to talk in another channel.

Answer (score 1):

You switch screens, I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>*#*</kbd> (*#* for channel number)